# ExtJs 5 how add item to dashboard programmatically?

Tags: dashboard, extjs5

I need some help. When creating dashboard I know that it need to fill parts object

```
parts: {
            portlet: {
                viewTemplate: {
                    layout: 'fit',
                    html: 'messafe from portlet'
                }
            },
            portlet2: {
                viewTemplate: {
                    layout: 'fit',
                    html: 'message from portlet2'
                }
            }
        }
```

also I know that I can use them below to render parts

```
defaultContent: [{
            type: 'portlet',
            title: 'Test1',
            columnIndex: 0,
            height: 500
        }, {
            type: 'portlet2',
            title: 'Test2',
            columnIndex: 1,
            height: 300
        }, {
            type: 'portlet',
            title: 'Test3',
            columnIndex: 1,
            height: 300
        }, {
            type: 'portlet',
            title: 'Test4',
            columnIndex: 2,
            height: 350
        }, {
            type: 'portlet',
            title: 'Test5',
            columnIndex: 3,
            height: 350
        }]
```

now my question is now add(do all this job) programmatically? for example I want to create new component on button click